# How to remove <br> tag from an empty tag in jodit editor?

Tags: meteor-blaze, rich-text-editor, jodit

Please help,
I am using Jodit Editor as a rich text editor, and I want to remove all the 
 tags in empty tags.

Currently getting:

```
<p><br><p>
```

Expected:

```
<p></p>
```

And I also tried to add:
enter: 'p', in the options.
But it didn't work!
Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You can configure this. Add the below lines in config object of jodit:

```
cleanHTML: {
fillEmptyParagraph: false
}
```